# Do I need a transit visa for Paris en route to Canada?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas

I booked an Air India flight from Amritsar to Toronto via Paris. In Paris, I have 15 hours before the flight to Canada. While booking, I was not told whether I would need a transit visa.

How can I confirm whether or not I need a transit visa for France? I have a student visa issued by Canada.

Comment: If you follow the guidelines in the linked duplicate answer, the answer appears to be "no, as long as you don't want to leave the airport."  Fifteen hours is a long time to be trapped in the airport, but I'm not sure it would be worth the hassle to try to get a more permissive visa for your layover.